# How to create chart ordered by months?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I really don't know how to create the following chart, Im working with Visual Studio 2015, c#, windows forms.

I want to create a chart(Column type) which shows the sum of sales for each month and each month sales separated by years.

I've the following MySql query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.IMPORT_BAS), MONTH(p.FECHA_PED), YEAR(p.FECHA_PED)
FROM
    pedidoscab p
WHERE
    p.FECHA_PED >= '2014-04-14'
        AND p.FECHA_PED <= '2016-04-14'
GROUP BY MONTH(p.FECHA_PED) , YEAR(p.FECHA_PED)
ORDER BY YEAR(p.FECHA_PED) , MONTH(p.FECHA_PED)
```

Example of result:

```
SUM(p.IMPORT_BAS),MONTH(p.FECHA_PED),YEAR(p.FECHA_PED)
88.0000,8,2015
1546718.6556,11,2015
1000001.0000,3,2016
14.0000,4,2016
```

The year range is an example.
For the people who don't understand what I want to do, there is an image that I found in google.

[image]

I don't need a line and I only need left and bottom labels (+ legend), and there can be empty values in one month, but the chart need to show all months always.

Comment: Can you add the code that reads-in the data? What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! You need to make sure to add the x-values as datetime and set the intervaltype to month and the intervall to 1..

Comment: Edited. Im trying a lot of ways to put the results in the chart, how do I put a value in a month?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example. Let's look at the result first:
[image]

Now for the code:

First a few references to make life  easier:

```
Axis XA = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
Axis YA = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
```

Now for test data. You will instead pull them from your `DataReader` or from the `DataTable`..!

```
// let's create 12 dates: 
// this year, first day of each month..:

List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    dates.Add( new DateTime(dt.Year, i, 1));
```

Now we add them to the points with a random y-value:

```
foreach (DateTime d in dates)
    S1.Points.AddXY(d, R.Next(99) + 33);
```

Let's style the chart a little:

```
// show the year in the legend:
S1.LegendText = "Year " + dt.Year;
// move to the bottom center:
chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
chart1.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

S1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;  // set the type
XA.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;         // no gridlines
XA.LabelStyle.Forma t = "MMM";         // show months as names

XA.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;  // show axis labels.. 
XA.Interval = 1;                                // ..every 1 months

YA.LabelStyle.Format = "##0$";  // for kilos etc you need to scale the y-values!
```

To create alternating bars in the background set use code like this:

```
YA.IsInterlaced = true;
YA.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
YA.InterlacedColor = Color.FromArgb(31, Color.LightSeaGreen);
```

Note that it will be best to actually add **exactly 12 values**. This makes life a lot easier when showing a year.

Therefore **databinding** to your query will not work directly. Instead you would need to separate the data by years into data structures of their own and add and bind a series for those years..

Or don't bind and add each point into the right series, maybe by using it as an indexer into the Series collection..

Answer (score 0):

you can use high charts like the following just replace values with you values :-

**HTML & Scripts**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit_text"></asp:Literal>
</body>
</html>
```

**C# Code**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lit_text.Text = @"<script>$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Bussiness Result 2005 v 2006'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '2005',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]  ,type: 'column'

        }, {
            name: '2006',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3],type: 'column'

        }, {
            name: 'Quality',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2],type: 'line'

        }]
    });
});</script>";
        }
```

Comment: I'm using c# not js.

Comment: u can use it using c# set literal under container div then from your c# code set literal.text with above text

Comment: I can help you using teamviewer if you want

Comment: Im not allowed to use teamviewer at work, whatever would be great if you can send me an example using that with c#, thank you anyways.

Comment: Ok give me one minute

Comment: The OP says WinForms.

Comment: are you wokring into WinForms you didn't said that this function not working on winform