# C# : display SQL query on a chart using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, charts

This is my query I want to display it like this: sum of commands by command date (each date should have a Bar that shows how many sales (commands) by that particular date (day)

```
select 
    date_comm as 'jourdetravail',
    sum(TotalCom) as 'recettedujour' 
from 
    Commande_art 
group by 
    date_comm
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you searched for a solution? Seems like something many people want to do. SO is not meant to your job for you. If you try something and get stuck, you'll find many people here willing to help, but you're asking for too much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620000/how-to-create-chart-ordered-by-months You could take a look at this question on SO.

Comment: thank you  @DanielKelsch this is what i exactly was looking for ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to fill a datatable and then use the datatable as source for the chart and also you will need the chart to be indexed on x axis

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<Your Server>;Initial Catalog=<YourDatabase>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<yourID>;Password=<yourPassword>");
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select [date_comm] as 'jourdetravail', sum([TotalCom]) as 'recettedujour' from [dbo].[Commande_art] group by [date_comm]";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

and then your "dt":

```
<yourChart>.DataSource = dt;
```

You will also need to set the 2 series of the chart with the same name of the column of the quesry in order to show them correctly